# Code or In Action scripts that validate whether UFT run by .vbs file or it run manually

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

Code or In  Action  scripts that validate whether UFT run by .vbs file or it run manually.... Eg:

```
If ( automatically_Variable) = True Then 
    Msgbox "UFT called Automatically"
Else 
    Msgbox " UFT called manually"
End If
```

Comment: It's unclear what your question is. See [ask] and then [edit] this question to tell us what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the test is run from ALM using the `IsInTestDirectorTest` settings variable (Test Director is the previous name of ALM).

```
If Setting("IsInTestDirectorTest") Then
    Print "Run from ALM"
Else
    Print "Not run from ALM"
End If
```

I don't know if there's a way to check if UFT was launched manually or via a script, if the script didn't make UFT visible you can check the visible flag.

```
Set uft = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")
If Not uft.Visible Then
    MsgBox "UFT called automatically"
Else
    MsgBox "UFT called manually"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

the qtpautomationagent.exe process is always started if you are using the COM automation(Quicktest.Application) to launch UFT. (

However if UFT crashes the Process may remain open even if you restart UFT (and the UFT exe) manually. It is also created if you create the Quicktest.Application Object inside a UFT run as well, so it is not that reliable.

You can think about UFT Environment variables, OS Environment variables or Flag Files at the end of the day it boils down to the same point: How do you make sure to cleanup dirty states (aka, UFT crashes)

The safest but less used alternative is **Test Parameters**. You can define them only for a specific run - aka when it is triggered from the vbs, other than that it should have a default value mentioning it is a manual run. The parameters will have the specific value for vbs only when triggered from it. Doesn't matter what happens afterwards, if you run the test case new values have to be defined. Define Test Parameters only for a specific Test Run [here](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/all/AutomationObjectModel/Default.htm#test/QuickTest%7ETest%7ERun.html%3FTocPath%3DTest%2520Object%7CMethods%7C_____8).

P.S: You can create an automation script that iterates over all your tests and creates this Test Parameter automatically. In your launching script you will just set a value specific to it.